# GPS location on BQ Aquaris E5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, aquaris, gps

I have a new Aquaris E5 HD, but it seems that GPS is not working. As far as I could find out, this issue is known for the E4.5, see  [GPS unvailable on aquaris E45](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603101/gps-unvailable-on-aquaris-e45).

I there any progress with that problem? On the E5 I am on the VegataHD rc-proposed channel version r266. There are many updates, but it seems that GPS is still dead. There is no application successfully getting a GPS position (including sensorStatus), and:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ ubuntu-location-serviced-cli --bus system --get --property does_satellite_based_positioning
```

reports

```
Location service does not satellite based positioning.
Attempted to unregister path (path[0] = com path[1] = ubuntu) which isn't registered
```

It seems the decive is not aware of its GPS capabilities.

Please note: This is about 'real' satellite based GPS, not the HERE stuff. This is working, with low precision of course, but it is completely useless in outdoor environments.

I know about the long time for getting a GPS fix, but I have exposed the phone to the clear sky several times for up to 2 hours without getting a fix.

A workaround would be to use an external bluetooth GPS receiver, but mine is not detected by the Bluetooth device discovery. Interestingly, the Bluettoth GPS is detected by 'hcitool scan' command, but I have no idea how to connect and how to get position data. I think gpsd is not ported to Ubuntu Touch.

Any help is welcome :-)

Thanks a lot

Comment: This sounds very interesting, for my device (nexus 4) GPS is not working (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/691468/how-to-use-gps-on-nexus-4) and I have the same report like in your post. How does the report look like for a device with working GPS?

Comment: Ok, since update today (r272), GPS is working. I get a fix after some minutes. "ubuntu-location-serviced-cli ..." now reports "Location service does satellite based positioning." Everything is fine now, my thanks to the developers!